# Find event launching the application: banner notification, alert notification or icon tap?

Tags: ios, push-notification

Can I find out which event launching the application on iOS ?

I need to distinguish between the followings:

1. Icon tap
2. Banner notification
3. Alert notification

Alternatively, can I view the application local settings (set for Banner or alert notification)?

Answer (score 4):

To determine if the app was launched from the using pressing a notification, you need to implement 2 methods.

First, in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, do something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
if ([launchOptions valueForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"]) {
 // Handle notification
}
```

Second:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    // The app was open when a remote notification was received...
} else {
    // The app was in the background and just came to the foreground in response to the user pressing the push notification
}
```

}

You can view which notification types have been enabled using:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

However, you can't distinguish between Banner or Alert notifications.